# Grabar en Firebase con la misma clave

Tags: android

Tengo una pequeña duda a la hora de grabar en Firebase.
Tengo este codigo:

```
            Map<String, Object> mapHisCostaleros = new HashMap<>();
                                        mapHisCostaleros.put("hisidportadores", gmidcostalero );
                                        mapHisCostaleros.put("hisnombrecostalero", gmnombreportador);
                                        mapHisCostaleros.put("histelefonomovil", gmmovilportador);
                                        mfirestoreHisCostaleros.collection("HisCostaleros").document(gmidcostalero).set(mapHisCostaleros);
```

Pues bien si paso una vez por supuesto lo graba, pero si paso por segunda vez y gmidcostalero  es el mismo lo que hace es no grabarlo pero modifica los demas valores si es que son distintos. No sale ningun error de que intento grabar la misma clave dos veces.

¿Esto es asi? Por que me soluciona un gran problema si es asi.

Gracias.

Comment: [Como podrás ver en la doc](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html) `set` crea el documento si no existe, y si existe agrega el nuevo contenido al documento.  Desde las opciones también puedes hacer un merge. No sé si estás pensando Firebase como las bases de datos tradicionales, lo cual sería un grave error, porque Fierebase es otra cosa. De hecho, es No SQL precisamente.